# Changing size of a shape in android xml

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to change the size of a oval shape with the following code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval"
android:thickness="70dp">
<solid android:color="@color/button_pressed" />
<size android:height="80dp"
    android:width="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

But it doesn't change the size a bit. What am I doing wrong?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Show control which using this shape.

Comment: edited with a selector

Comment: You have just created the shape of the component. The size won't be changed till you put desired values(I suppose 80dp) in your component.xml

Comment: Component.xml ?

Comment: you do not need to set shape size , when you set selector on a button or any other view then shape size will depend on button ,  if you set button size to 200dp width and hight  then shape will be displayed as 200dp size

Comment: Figured that out today, but still thanks. I fixed it by just making objects on my png's a bit smaller so there was more free room on the sides of the image and now it looks ok